# Fire jquery events in a Laravel view

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Typically, you may instantiate a Laravel 5.4 view like so:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
});
```

Now I want to use jQuery to perform various front-end tasks on HTML elements defined in the view during the life-cycle of that view - on initialize, on render, on destroy.

I suppose another way of asking this question is: how do I get a client-side javascript function to run after a Laravel view has been loaded?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { // do your thing })` is as close to what you want as you'll get with jquery.

Comment: You can use `$( document ).ready()` to run something on page load or initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick your JS in the view, the same as you would do with any HTML page.

Then maybe start moving your JS into separate files.

Then maybe start versioning you assets.

Then maybe take a look at Vue.js.

Mick